# How to rotate a binary embedded image in a graphic containing Postscript?

Tags: graphics, notebooks, compatibility

We have a collection of old notebooks containing cells with Postscript graphics. They relied on various external programs to help generate them so I can't regenerate these easily in a newer version of Wolfram Language. The notebooks open in a Front End without a problem and any of the Postscript that isn't read in with the currentfile command renders fine. Unfortunately, when a graphic contains an embedded image, the embedded image may be rendered upside down.

In the image below, the label 689 is rendered properly, but the CA graphic should be rotated 180 degrees. I can't rotate the whole image without rotating the label. This is a simple example and there are others with grids of small images with labels and just those images need 180 degree rotations. I've added a notebook with the image below to see if anyone has an idea as to how to get this working.

I've tried the following: 1. extracted the cell into a .m file 2. inserted rotation and other postscript commands to attempt to rotate the graphic just a little bit (eg rotate 5 or change the transformation matrix) 3. ran the .m through WolframKernel to export a png graphic

This fails as even "rotate 5" seemingly fails to rotate the coord system. Translate commands move the graphic object, but rotate doesn't rotate. I'm not sure why.

I've consulted others about this, but I can't find an expert on Mathematica and Postscript who might be able to give some advice.

[image: CA Image that is upside down]

"Show Expression" for one of these graphic cells is like the following:

```
Cell[GraphicsData["PostScript", "\<\   
%!   
%%Creator: Mathematica   
%%AspectRatio: .81    
MathPictureStart...   
% Start of user PostScript   
 2      
   gsave      
   Mabswid     
   currentlinewidth    
   dup      
   grestore     
   2 copy translate    
   exch      
   2 mul      
   1 exch sub exch    
   2 mul      
   0.81 exch sub    
   0.81 div     
   scale   
% End of user PostScript   
% Start of user PostScript   
gsave   
1.000000 0.810000 scale   
243 string   
100 81 8 [100 0 0 -81 0 81]   
\t{ currentfile 1 index readhexstring pop }   
false 3 colorimage   
00FF00FF0000FF00000000FF00FF00FF0000FF000000FF00FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF00000000FFFF000000FF0000FF0000\   
...   
000000FF00FF0000FF000000FF0000FFFF0000FF0000FF00000000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF   

pop   
grestore   

% End of user PostScript   
MathSubEnd   
P   
% End of sub-graphic   
0 g   
p   
/Courier findfont 10 scalefont setfont   
[(689)] .5 0 0 1 Mshowa   
P   
0 0 m   
1 0 L   
1 .81 L   
0 .81 L   
closepath   
clip   
newpath   
% End of Graphics   
MathPictureEnd   
\   
\>"], "Graphics",   
 Evaluatable->False,   
 AspectRatioFixed->True,   
 ImageSize->{282, 228},   
 ImageMargins->{{34, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}]
```

Comment: Any chance you could post a link to one of these notebooks, say via the cloud? I can think of a few possible approaches to handle this but I can't test them without sample data

Comment: I've figured out how to do this. I had to write a script that takes the lines after "false 3 colorimage" and reverses them. So the last line becomes the first, etc... I've managed to fix a few complicated notebooks this way.

Comment: Sounds good. You might also think about writing a small parser to get the data into a Mathematica `Graphics` format so that the stuff can be manipulated natively.